# Dividing a Checkerboard into L-Shaped Regions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, induction

In preparation for the GRE Math-Subject test, and honestly for the fun of it, I've been working through a select number of my texts. The first of which is Saracino's Abstract Algebra text. I was hoping this wouldn't happen, but I've been very quickly stumped.

The following is Exercise 0.22, and I'm looking for a few hints.

"Prove that the follow statement is true for any integer $n \geq 1$: If the number of squares in a "checkerboard" is $2^n \times 2^n$ and we remove any one square, then the remaining part of the board can be broken up into L-shaped regions each consisting of 3 squares."

Before I wrote this proof, I went ahead and pulled out a sheet of paper and did a little testing, because I'm not exactly sure if all of these have to be correct. I found that I could remove pretty much any square on the $2^2 \times 2^2$ board and not be able to break it up. This leads me to believe that the statement is false. Any advice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can prove this using induction.

Our trivial base case is $n=2$.

Now, assume that the statement is true for $n-1$

[image: Sorry for the bad image!]

We can split a $2^n\times 2^n$ board into four $2^{n-1} \times 2^{n-1}$ boards, as shown above. W.L.O.G. the square that we choose to take out is in the upper right quadrant. Since a $2^{n-1} \times 2^{n-1}$ board can be filled with Ls if one square is taken out, the upper right quadrant can be filled without any issue. Now, suppose we take out the L shape in the middle of the board (which is highlighted in red in the picture above). Then each of the other quadrants will have one square missing, and thus can be filled with Ls. Since the shape in the middle itself is an L, the whole board can be filled with Ls. (Sorry for the bad english.)

Comment: I'm not sure if we can remove an entire quadrant. As I understand if, no matter how large the board gets, we only remove one of those checkers. So, considering that 4x4, you have three 2x2s that cannot be subdivided. But I might be fundamentally misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: @Ryan Honea Right, I never said to remove an entire quadrant (sorry for the bad english). I'm saying that you can fill in the quadrant from which you took that 1 square. Then, imagine (temporarily) taking out the L shape in the middle. Then, we can fill every other quadrant, since each is missing one piece. Then, we can put back the L piece, which can obviously itself be filled with L pieces.

Comment: I guess that's my point. Take out a single square from that upper right one, and you won't be able to fill it.

Comment: @RyanHonea Actually, that's where the induction comes in. We provide a base case, assume that the statement is true for $n-1$, and then prove that it is true for $n$. In this case, the $n-1$ case assumption is that we can fill in a $2^{n-1}\times 2^{n-1}$ quadrant if any one square is removed. For further details on induction: http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mathematical_induction

Comment: I think that you might be confused because you are subdividing more than you should be. We only have to subdivide the chessboard into 4 quadrants. The image that I have above should be thought of as a general $2^n \times 2^n$ board, not an $8\times 8$ board

Comment: I finally get it! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It is obviously true for $2\times 2$. As an advice, when you see $2^n$ try to divide it into two parts consisting of $2^{n-1}$ and use induction. In your case, divide the whole board into $4$ $2^{n-1}\times 2^{n-1}$ boards.

### Edit:

Without loss of generality, suppose we remove a square in the up-right quadrant. Then, on the up-right we have $2^{n-1}\times 2^{n-1}$ square whose exactly one square is removed.

For the remaining three quadrants, we will want to use the induction hypothesis on each one of them. So, place an $L$-shaped tile in the center of the big square, like the following($+$ is the removed square and $\times$s are the $L$-shaped tile):
$$\begin{matrix}
\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\\
\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\\
\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&+&\square&\square&\\
\square&\square&\square&\times&\square&\square&\square&\square&\\
\square&\square&\square&\times&\times&\square&\square&\square&\\
\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\\
\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\\
\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\square&\\
\end{matrix}$$
This tile covers exactly one square of the three remaining quadrants. So, we have $4$ $2^{n-1}\times2^{n-1}$ boards, each have exactly $1$ square covered(removed). Thus, by the induction hypothesis, we can cover each smaller boards with $L$-shaped tiles. By gluing all these coverings together we obtain a covering for the big board.

Comment: If we are only able to remove one piece though, then even if we have 4 2x2 squares, only one 2x2 can be subdivided. The rest can't be subdivided.

Comment: One of the four smaller boards will have a square removed, which we can cover by induction hypothesis. For the rest of three, put an $L$ shaped tile in a way that the $L$ shaped tile covers exactly one square from the remaining three boards. Can you see where you should put the last tile? Think about where the three tiles all get together. As you're asking for a hint, I'm trying to avoid giving out the full solution.

Comment: At this point, I might need it. I believe I might completely misunderstand this problem.

Comment: I edited the solution for you. I hope this new one helps

Comment: Thanks so much! I understand now haha.